# Running Responder outputs many hashes per user, how is this possible?

Tags: hash, ntlm

I am running [Responder](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/Responder) on Kali Linux within a client network using the following command

```
sudo responder -I eth0 -w -r -d
```

which is capturing many hashes in the environment. Responder is a LLMNR, NBT-NS and MDNS poisoner used for MITM attacks. Essentially it waits for users to enter an incorrect DNS name and then acts as an SMB share with the incorrect DNS name, to which the users send NTLMv2 hashes to authenticate, which can then be stolen. According to the documentation I should get a John-Jumbo formatted list of hashes which belong to the users. However I can't seem to understand the output. It has captured hashes for 4-5 users but the number of hashes is around 30,000 hashes. The output of Responder (the captured NTLMv2 hashes) essentially looks like

user1:hash1

user1:hash2

user1:hash3

user2:hash4

And so on. One user has nearly 20,000 NTLMv2 hashes in the output. How is this possible? Why would a single user have 20,000 hashes?

Comment: @mentallurg Added explanations for the items you requested, and a description of what Responder does. Let me know if it looks Ok.

Comment: 1) Why don't you think that what you see is not correct? 2) Show what you have done so far, show what documentation says, explain what environment are you using (network, devices, etc.)

Comment: @mentallurg Added the requested information. The core issue is that Responder says that one user sends multiple thousands of different NTLMv2 hashes but I'm unclear as to what that means exactly. Should a single user not be limited to one hash+salt for their authentication?